# How to populate a nested category table with Faker in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model, faker, laravel-seeding

I want to put the subcategory id into quote table but it seems too complicated! This is my try, obviously it ended up with a loop.

Here is the seeder:

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function ($u) {

        $u->quotes()->save(
            factory(App\Quote::class)->make()
        );

    });
}
```

And the quote factory:

```
return [
    'text' => $faker->paragraph,
    'author_id' => factory('App\Author')->create()->id,
    'category_id' => factory('App\Category')->create()->id
];
```

The category factory:

```
return [
    'name' => $faker->text,
    'parent_id' => factory('App\Category')->create()->id
];
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @dwjohnston I would imagine it's an infinite loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you're using Laravel >=5.3, I would suggest using [states](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database-testing#factory-states).

For you default category factory make the `parent_id` = `null` e.g.

```
$factory->define(App\Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name'      => $faker->text,
        'parent_id' => null
    ];
});
```

Then you can add a state factory to include the parent category:

```
$factory->state(App\Category::class, 'child', function ($faker) {
    return [
        'parent_id' => factory('App\Category')->create()->id,
    ];
});
```

To use the state, you just need to chain on a method called `states()` with the name of the state e.g.

```
factory(App\Category::class)->states('child')->make();
```

---

If you're using Laravel <=5.2 then I would just suggest keeping the `parent_id` = null and then just passing the `parent_id` manually e.g.

```
$parent = factory(App\Quote::class)->create();
$u->quotes()->save(
    factory(App\Quote::class)->make(['parent_id' => $parent->id])
);
```

---

I would also recommend wrapping any factory calls from within a factory in a closure.

```
'parent_id' => function () {
   return factory('App\Category')->create()->id;
}
```

This way will only ever create the model when it's needed. If you ever override the value by passing your own id, it won’t actually trigger the function, where as if it wasn’t wrapped in a closure it would call the factory whether or not you passing in an id to override it.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing) for more information.

Comment: Thanx for adding the info about the closure, really useful!